# SPEL expression does not work with #{#entityName} in @Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

The following queries work:

```
@Query("select o from Employee o where o.tenant.id = ?#{context.tenantId}")

@Query("select o from #{#entityName} o where o.tenant.id = 1")
```

But if I use both expressions together an exception is thrown at the startup.

```
@Query("select o from #{#entityName} o where o.tenant.id = ?#{context.tenantId}")
```

Exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E:(pos 0): Property or field 'context' cannot be found on null
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:222)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:89)
at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:136)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ExpressionBasedStringQuery.renderQueryIfExpressionOrReturnQuery(ExpressionBasedStringQuery.java:71)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ExpressionBasedStringQuery.<init>(ExpressionBasedStringQuery.java:48)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.<init>(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:57)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:55)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:51)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:202)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:80)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Tested with spring-data-jpa 1.7.1 and 1.8.0-snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a bug, I'm already working on a fix. I filed https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-629 to track this.
Edit: I added a fix for this to the JIRA issue - would you mind giving it a try?

Comment: hello, I faced a problem in using entity name as a parameter. I want to select the data from parameter and use the parameter in left join, is is possible? 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51311256/spring-data-jpa-spel-support-does-not-work-in-select-left-join`